# How to set global settings in Scrapy in Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: web-scraping, scrapy, scrapy-shell

It is given that setting is in "scrapy.settings.default_settings" Module, but I am unable to find it. Is it a text file or something? How to access it?

Answer (score 0):

`scrapy.settings.default_settings` is a inbuilt python module with default setting constants.

You cannot change that outside from forking scrapy itself, however there are plenty of other ways to set settings:

https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html